# How does \hline work?

Tags: tables, tex-core

Looking at `\hline`, I ran into a couple complex pieces:

## `\meaning\hline`

```
macro:->\noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet
        \reserved@a \@xhline
```

## `\meaning\@xhline`

```
macro:->\ifx \reserved@a \hline \vskip \doublerulesep 
        \vskip -\arrayrulewidth \fi \ifnum 0=`{\fi }
```

It seems the `\@xhline` code is closing the `\ifnum` conditional. Could someone provide an explanation of what is going on with `` {\ifnum 0=`} ``

Comment: You're reporting badly the code. Anyway, those are very smart tricks for contributing a brace without TeX suspecting we're doing it.

Comment: @egreg I just copied and pasted from PDF. Maybe I should have used `\show` instead of `\meaning` and copied from the terminal. I will check everything when I get home.

Comment: the ifnum brace trick is explained in some detail in appendix D of the TeXBook

Comment: @egreg I double-checked the code with `\show` and it appears to be the same. What do you mean when you say that I am reporting the code badly?

Comment: @macmadness86 There were some backslashes, now removed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the definition in the source file

```
% latex.ltx, line 5351:
\def\hline{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet
   \reserved@a\@xhline}
\def\@xhline{\ifx\reserved@a\hline
               \vskip\doublerulesep
               \vskip-\arrayrulewidth
             \fi
      \ifnum0=`{\fi}}
```

The responsibility of `\hline` is to add a horizontal rule and to look forward for another `\hline`. In order to do this, TeX is temporarily put outside the alignment, with the help of `\noalign`. The code

```
\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
```

opens the token list for `\noalign`, and the closing brace is not seen because it is part of a numeric test returning false. TeX expands tokens as it goes, performs the necessary assignments; in particular, `\hrule` is executed and then `\futurelet` is called to see whether another `\hline` command follows (for adding a small vertical space). Finally

```
\ifnum0=`{\fi}
```

is found, which closes the token list for `\noalign` and gets TeX back in doing the alignment.

Why not `\bgroup` and `\egroup`? They would work here, but it's preferable to have those explicit braces in case `\hline` gets expanded prematurely so the brace counter is fooled into thinking that they appear in a pair.

Comment: So if I understand you, the test is whether `0` and `\`` are equal?  Why is the first `\ifnum0=\`}` not `\ifnum0=\`{` as in the TeXBook Appendix D p.385? Does it have to do with the reversed increase/decrease counter of alphabetic constants?

Comment: @macmadness86 In the first case we want a closing brace for ”balancing“ the opening one.

Comment: @macmadness86 it is comparing 0 with ``}` (don't know how to get just backquote brace in the text) which is the character `}`, thereby swallowing up the `}` so that it doesn't close the group. And at the end it is the reverse.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum You have to escape the metacharacter *grave accent* with a backslash to type it literally. e.g.: `\`}`. Thanks for the helpful clarification. This is certainly a "dirty" TeX trick. Usually conditional operators have single token operands. You'd have to know the comment egreg will type below to understand it ;)

Comment: @macmadness86 Sorry, I didn't get your doubt: when TeX is looking for a number, for instance in the context of `\ifnum`, the combination `\`<char>` denotes an *alphabetical constant*, so the whole `\`}` is a number.

Comment: @egreg I am curious how `\hline` might get expanded prematurely. Prematurely to what? This method is used in other `\noalign{...}`s.

Comment: @macmadness86 People try to hack LaTeX in many ways…