# What does {\ifnum\z@=`}\fi mean?

Tags: macros

Reading `physics.sty` available on CTAN as `physics` package I found the line

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\quantity{}{{\ifnum\z@=`}\fi\@quantity}
```

which I don't understand. I is clear that `\quantity` is defined as a call to `\@quantity`. But what the construct

```
{\ifnum\z@=`}\fi
```

do?

Comment: It's a trick to have an unbalanced brace. This [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339143/82917) explains a similar case.

Comment: It's for when you have something looking ahead for a literal brace and `\bgroup` wouldn't do.

Comment: If you look at the definition of `\@quantity` you'll see that it ends with ``\ifnum\z@=`{\fi}``, which provides the closing brace.

Comment: I still wonder. `\z@` is just zero, and ``}` is octal code of the closing brace, right? So, `{\ifnum\z@=`}\fi` is always evaluated to false and skipped. What is then the difference of `\DeclareDocumentCommand\quantity{}{{\ifnum\z@=`}\fi\@quantity}` from `\let\quantity\@quantity`?

Comment: See _The TeXbook_, Appendix D, section 5 (_Brace Hacks_).

Comment: The difference is that `\let\quantity\@quantity` doesn't make anything useful `;-)` With the current definition `\quantity` _opens a group_ and calls `\@quantity`, which at the end closes the group. Probably `\bgroup` and `\egroup` might have been enough too, but sometimes the trick with `\ifnum` is better (see e.g. the answer I linked).

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov The trick is the brace before the \ifnum. It will stay while the closing brace after the ifnum will disappear.

Comment: Reading the code there's no reason whatsoever for using that brace trick, nor for defining `\@quantity`; actually, `\begingroup` at the beginning and `\endgroup` at the end would fit better. The definition should be `\NewDocumentCommand{\quantity}{<arg spec as for \@quantity>}{\begingroup<code as for \@quantity>\endgroup}`

Comment: I find `\z@` quite a cryptic command. To begin with, it is buried in Appendix B of the TexBook (p. 348), defined as `0` or `0pt`. The definition is not easy to find in the Internet. :-\

Answer (score 5):

Just follow the expansions. If TeX finds the call

```
\quantity\big(x)
```

it will do

```
{\ifnum\z@=`}\fi\@quantity\big(x)
```

Now TeX expands tokens or pushes them through the gullet. In this case `{` is pushed down (and a simple group is opened) and `\ifnum` is expanded. Since the test is false, only `\fi` remains (actually it's irrelevant that the test is false). The expansion of `\fi` is empty and TeX proceeds to expand `\@quantity`.

This is more complicated and the subsequent processing involves some `\let`, which are the reason for doing everything in a group. The end result is

```
\bigl(x\bigr)\ifnum\z@=`{\fi}
```

After expansions and executions, the math list corresponding to `\bigl(x\bigr)` is built and finally `\ifnum` is expanded, leaving again nothing behind it; the trailing `}` closes the group started at the beginning.

If we look at what we got, that macro call is essentially the same as doing

```
{\bigl(x\bigr)}
```

which is *wrong*. For instance,

```
\log\quantity\big(x)
```

would result in a thin space between the operator and the parentheses, because

```
\log{\bigl(x)\bigr)}
```

treats the subformula in braces as a unique *ordinary* symbol. Here's the visual proof:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}

$\log\quantity\big(x)$

$\log\bigl(x\bigr)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

This wouldn't happen if the definition is

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\quantity{ t\big t\Big t\bigg t\Bigg g o d() d|| }
{\begingroup
 % Flexible automatic bracketing of an expression in () or [] or {} or ||
        % Handles manual override of sizing
 [...many lines of code...]
        {\ltag\lbrace#5\rtag\rbrace  \IfNoValueTF{#6}{}{[#6]} \IfNoValueTF{#7}{}{(#7)} \IfNoValueTF{#8}{}{|#8|}}
        \endgroup
}
```

I see no reason for a separate macro `\@quantity`. Using a *semisimple* group avoids the problem with a subformula:

```
\log\begingroup\bigl(x\bigr)\endgroup
```

does not consider the tokens in the group to make a subformula and the spacing between the Op atom `\log` and the Open atom `\bigl(` would be the right one.

Answer (score 4):

The coder wanted the `\quantity` macro to expand to `{\fi\@quantity`. However, this does not work in a macro definition as the `{` is not closed and the TeX compiler would look for the closing `}` further on. To still get this done a trick is used to add a `}` which is taken as a closing group during macro definition but is ignored (i.e. removed) during macro execution.

This is done by adding `` \ifnum\z@=`}\fi `` so the macro *definition* has now matching braces so the compiler is happy here. Then during macro *execution* the `` ` `` actually turns the `}` into a number  (its ASCII number AFAIK). This number is compared with `\z@` (=0) using `\ifnum\z@=` just to remove it again without producing any output. As the closing `\fi` is following directly thereafter the whole thing `` \ifnum\z@=`}\fi `` expands to nothing independent on the actually number value.

For this to work there should be a matching `` \ifnum 0=`{\fi} `` following in a macro which is called later on in the process.

One other place this is used is in `\hline`. See the [explanation there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339143/2975).

Comment: The coder wanted that but he's wrong in wanting it to begin with. `;-)`